# getting wrong latitude & longitude from geocoding

Tags: php, json, geocoding

I have a geocoding function that is pulling the address values entered into a form and putting them into the geocoding call. The response is supposed to write the latitude & longitude values into the DB - unfortunately, my lat & longs are all coming back as Antarctica. Thoughts?

```
//Set up our variables
$longitude = "";
$latitude = "";


//Three parts to the querystring: q is address, output is the format (
$key=$er_mapapi; 
$address=str_replace(' ', '%20', $_REQUEST['street_num'] . ' ' . $_REQUEST['address2'] . ', ' . $loccity . ', ' . $ststate . ', ' . $_REQUEST['postcode'] . ', ' . $cncount); 
$url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=".$address."&output=json&key=".$key;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$geo_json = json_decode($data, true);

print_r($geo_json);

if ($geo_json['Status']['code'] == '200') {


$latitude = $geo_json['Placemark'][0]['Point']['coordinates'][0];
$longitude = $geo_json['Placemark'][0]['Point']['coordinates'][1];


echo "Latutide: $latitude \n";
echo "Longitude: $longitude \n";

if ($latitude != '') $row->declat = $latitude; if ($longitude != '') $row->declong = $longitude; 


} else {
echo "Error in geocoding! Http error ".substr($data,0,3);
}
```

Comment: Please show an example of an address, and the long/lat data you are getting.

Comment: okay, I figured out that it is switching the latitude & longitude....but why?

Comment: @Pekka - see comment above. It's putting the values into the wrong order

Comment: Also show a typical VAR_DUMP of $_REQUEST for key/value pairs in addition to the address line prior to processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be other errors, but to start it looks like [KML returns point coordinates in (long, lat) order](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kmlreference.html#point), and you're expecting the opposite.

Comment: so in the above code - do I switch the 1 and 0 for the $latitude and $longitude values?

Comment: that fixed it - thanks for the help and @Pekka, thanks for the help in the other thread.